# jquery.ajax in Visualforce

Tags: ajax

I don't konw whether there are some error in my code, so does anyone have experiences about use jquery.ajax in Visualforce or how to post a request to an external service in Visualforce?

When this code execute, I receieve the response with error method: textStatus : error XMLHttpRequest.readyState : 0 XMLHttpRequest.status : 0

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'https://www.me.com/qualification', // outside Domain
     headers: {"Accept" : "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json" },
     data: JSON.stringify(address),
     crossDomain : true,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (responseData) {
        console.log(responseData);
    getAddresses();

    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
        var result = $("#selections").append("Sorry, Something in the system has gone wrong , Please try again Later");
        console.log("Sorry, Something in the system has gone wrong , Please try again Later");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely related to browser security policy as described in the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation:

- Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.
- Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

Using [JSONP](https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/) as a work-around is a common approach, but does require the URL you are addressing to support JSONP.

Comment: You are absolutely correct but I just figured out why mine wasnt working. I cant have a submit button in apex form. and that is why it wasnt working